# Add class to sub-taxonomy terms

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to add a class to my subterms in a taxonomy vocabulary? So I can style theme and indent them. This is my taxonomy vocabulary:

[image]

And in my front-end it looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to `remove the "-"` and give them a `padding-left`. But how can I do this?

I'm showing this as a term reference in my registration form shown as checkboxes.

Comment: how are you showing these in frontend, as a menu?

Comment: This is a term reference in my registration form shown as checkboxes.

Comment: Can you just paste the markup for this list?

Comment: @nielsv which version of Drupal are you using? D7?

Comment: Im using drupal 7.

Comment: @nielsv - Hope [This post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/85011/25879) may helps you.

Comment: @Krishna Mohan - I don't really get it. Which function should I overwrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using them in a form you could use this module to have much more control of your checkboxes tree and you will have different classes for parents and children:

https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree

1. Enable the Term Reference Tree module.
2. Go to the Manage Fields tab of any fieldable entity (such as a content type, taxonomy term, or user.
3. Add a new field with a type of Term Reference.
4. In the widget select box, select Term reference tree.